# Compute significance of Kendall tau-b?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, kendall-tau

I have so-far tried all ways of computing [kendall tau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) significance (where there are ties) described.

However, none of them works good, even for relatively large vectors. I think the problem is in general it seems that these methods tend to overestimate the statistical significance of data, so are there any alternative ways to compute kendall tau's significance? (at least get some degree of tie-adjustments)?

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly the adjustments don't work?

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa I compare the significance computed by these methods with the exact significance level computed from permutations.

Comment: In that case, could you just use that permutation test to assess significance? For larger vectors, you could probably not go through *all* permutations, but 10,000 random permutations are often already enough.

Comment: Sure, but the computational cost is huge (in some cases when you may not satisified with some 0.05 significance level).

Comment: If the number of permutations required is too large (though there are some clever techniques for reducing the computational burden), why not simply sample the permutations (i.e. perform a randomization test) to whatever degree of accuracy you can afford?

Comment: I see. Tail ends of distributions are always hard to get a handle on, and approximations (such as the ones on the Wikipedia page) often break down exactly there. Sorry, I have no idea how to help you there... Have you looked at the references given on the Wikipedia page?

Comment: @Glen_b: this is what I proposed, but the OP seems to be interested in the very outer tail ends of the empirical distribution. The number of sampled permutations necessary to get a handle on the top and bottom 0.1% of a distribution is orders of magnitude larger than the number of permutations needed for the top and bottom 2.5% (for the standard 5% alpha level).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Maybe there's something I am missing, but it seems fairly straightforward to generate the most extreme ones. That's what the various specialized 'exact' permutation test algorithms try to do (eg various papers by Mehta, Patel and some of their coauthors, as well as a number of others) - specifically to move through the extreme permutations of various statistics in order from most extreme, in efficient ways. Is there a reason why such approaches can't be used/adapted to work with tau-b? Ties complicate it, but I don't think they'll prevent those approaches from being used.

Comment: @Glen_b, I am trying to do such computations with quite large data sets in a time-critical application so efficiency is a conern. Btw, I checked the matlab's own kendall' tau function, anyone know why mathsworks's z-score is slightly modified `(abs(nc-nd)-1)` instead of `(abs(nc-nd))` before divided by std, is there any paper for this modification of tau-b's z-score (two-tail)?

Comment: @user55647 Its possible the "-1" might be a continuity correction.

Comment: Are there any justifications for doing this? because of this modification made the tau-b's significance changed quite significantly for small size case, thanks.

Comment: Is this reference any use to you? Valz, P.D. and Thompson, M.E. (1994), Exact inference for Kendall’s S and Spearman’s rho. Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 3, 459–472.  I can't check it right now, but reading around things that refer to it, it looks to be relevant.

Comment: @Glen_b: thanks for the references to improving the tail end behavior of permutation tests, I wasn't aware of them!

Comment: @StephanKolassa It's not so much the behavior as the computation time with those, though I have seen references that relate to better tail approximations along the way as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since the denominator only depends on the margins, not on the association, the exact permutation p-value is the same for any of the statistics that has $N_c-N_d$ on the numerator (Kendall's tau, tau-b, tau-c, Somer's-D etc).

There are algorithms for computing p-values of all these measures of association for ordinal data efficiently, by taking account of the ordering of the permutations induced by some simple form of the test statistic, and only considering the ones more extreme than the test statistic (or considering as few additional ones as possible), generally arising from ideas based on Mehta and Patel's networking algorithm, though there have been developments and ideas from many authors.

Some stats packages implement such algorithms. It might be worth checking whether some of the exact-test related packages already have an efficient version of it for some version of the Kendall statistic.

For example, I believe SPSS Exact Tests has this implemented for the Kendall tau.

(Out of curiosity, why would it matter for you if you were only able to get a probabilistic *bound* on the p-value using resampling? How does (say) knowing the p-value is almost certainly less that $3.2 \times 10^{-5}$ rather than computing it to be exactly $1.6245 \times 10^{-6}$? What additional information does that give you?)